# Invalid indirect reference 0x416f68a0 in decodeIndirectRef

Tags: android, android-ndk, java-native-interface

I've seen plenty of questions about exactly the same error, but none of them seems to be trying to do this simple thing and still fail.

I have in my class header, as private members:

```
static JNIEnv* env;
static jclass copterServiceClass;
static jmethodID mavlinkMsgMethod;
```

Then in the source for that class:

```
JNIEnv* JU_Calls::env = 0;
jclass JU_Calls::copterServiceClass = 0;
jmethodID JU_Calls::mavlinkMsgMethod = 0;

bool JU_Calls::setupJNICalls() {

    if (cached_jvm->GetEnv(reinterpret_cast<void**>(&env), JNI_VERSION_1_6) != JNI_OK) {
        __android_log_print(ANDROID_LOG_ERROR, TAG, "Unable to get Java Env from cached JavaVM");
        return -1;
    }

    jclass dataClass = env->FindClass("eu/deye/copterdroidair/copterdroidair/Services/CopterService");
    copterServiceClass = (jclass) env->NewGlobalRef(dataClass);
    mavlinkMsgMethod = env->GetMethodID(copterServiceClass, "MavlinkMsg", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");

    jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(copterServiceClass, mavlinkMsgMethod);
    jstring msg = env->NewStringUTF("aaaa");
    env->CallVoidMethod(javaObjectRef, mavlinkMsgMethod, msg);

    return true;
}
```

Note: `cached_jvm` is assigned at `JNI_OnLoad`.

It fails with the aforementioned error when executing `NewObject`.

> Invalid indirect reference 0x416f68a0 in decodeIndirectRef

I tried passing NULL to the `CallVoidMethod` as the message, as seen on other's questions, but as it's logical, the problem is before, so useless.

Hope you can help me, as always, great SO masters ;)

EDIT: While I think Bangyno answer is the right one, what I've eventually done to solve the problem as quickest as possible, was to declare the Java Methods that would be called from C++ as static. That way I don't have to call the constructor, and everything makes a lot more sense. Because the Java class to which I was calling, was an Android Service, thus calling the constructor was erroneous for sure.

Apart from declaring the Java method **static**, the resulting C++ code results as follows:

```
jclass copterServiceClass = env->FindClass("eu/deye/copterdroidair/copterdroidair/Services/CopterService");
jmethodID mavlinkMsgMethod = env->GetStaticMethodID(copterServiceClass, "MavlinkMsg", "(ILjava/lang/String;)V");
jstring msg = env->NewStringUTF(str);
env->CallStaticVoidMethod(copterServiceClass, mavlinkMsgMethod, severity, msg);
env->DeleteLocalRef(msg);
```

Is very important not to forget the last line, because otherwise it will fill your JNI table and crash.

Comment: Where is `setupJNICalls` called from? Also, you have very little error checking. You should check the return value and/or execption status after each JNI call.

Comment: Oh, and the second argument to `NewObject` should obviously be the `jmethodID` of one of `CopterService`'s constructors.

Comment: That makes sense, but I was following http://www.mobileway.net/2015/03/20/android-pro-tip-call-java-methods-from-c-using-jni/ and that method does not seem to be a constructor... What do you think? Thanks!

Comment: You'd have to ask the person that wrote the tutorial. Personally I don't think it looks correct and I would make sure to follow [the official documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) instead.

Comment: The value 0x416f68a0 looks like a pointer rather than an indirect reference. That could happen if the method ID were passed when an object was expected, but I don't see anything doing that in the code you posted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here I want to discuss is the error message:

> Invalid indirect reference 0x416f68a0 in decodeIndirectRef

It means you give the wrong argument, the second one "mavlinkMsgMethod".
In my experience, if you change *"mavlinkMsgMethod"* to a number such as *"5"*, the *0x416f68a0* will change to *0x5*.

The right way to use newObject is use  to invoke the constructor. It should look like this, just a sample:

```
jclass dataClass = env->FindClass("eu/deye/copterdroidair/copterdroidair/Services/CopterService");
mavlinkMsgMethod = env->GetMethodID(copterServiceClass, "<init>", "(Ljava/lang/String;)V");
jstring str = env->NewStringUTF("testing");    
jobject javaObjectRef = env->NewObject(copterServiceClass, mavlinkMsgMethod, str);
```